# Infinite products of non-measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I just proved for a homework problem that the direct product of two non-measurable sets is non-measurable. It seems to me that the finite direct product of finitely many non-measurable sets is also definitely non-measurable. But what about infinite products? I would imagine that uncountably infinitely many non-measurable sets might potentially be measurable, since uncountable products tend to do strange things. Does anyone know the conditions for when products of non-measurable sets is non-measurable? Could you point me to a proof?

Comment: Leesburg measure is only defined on $\Bbb{R}^n$ for finite $n$. In which space do you imagine the infinite product to lie?  In particular, which sigma-algebra and which measure are you using on that space? Or do you mean something different than Cartesian products?